# Can a foot soldier kill a dragon? If yes, are there any examples from the past on how did they do it?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As the question says, can a foot soldier kill a dragon? For example, let's suppose Jon turns against Daenerys and comes face to face with Drogon. Can he kill the dragon with the tools he has at hand? For clarification, the tools aren't necessarily limited to one on one combat. For the intent of the question, all existing technology and soldiers at his command shall be considered tools.

Comment: You can kill almost anything using the same techniques.
Poison food, hurt vital organ, sneak attack, trap, nest, rock, drown, strangle, bleed to death,  
The question assume some kind of invulnerability to common things or direct fight.
Perhaps can just jam the signal screaming "No drakaris, NOO!" till the dragon ignore any order. If caveman could kill mammoth, I don't see how one can fail to kill a tamed beast.

Comment: Chill.. Jon isn't going to die. Bran will warg into it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It *could*, strong could, be possible for Jon to kill Drogon under current means. Firstly, there might be prototype scorpions or some of the first versions that Bronn used laying around somewhere in the Red Keep he could use and attack him when he's not expecting it.

However, it is also possible to kill a dragon with just hand weapons as we saw at the Storming of the Dragonpit. Granted these dragons were smaller, younger and not as strong as Drogon as they had been chained up under the Dragonpit for some time but it isn't too much of a stretch to apply what we know of it from there to Drogon.

At the Storming of the Dragonpit five dragons died, most be some means of hack and slash with hand weapons rather than anything more sophisticated.

> **Pycelle:** For over a hundred years, the Targaryen dragons cemented their breeders' hold on the Seven Kingdoms, if not each other. When Targaryen fought Targaryen in the civil war called the Dance of the Dragons, an angry mob stormed the Dragonpit, that huge, now-ruined vault where Targaryens stabled their beasts. Thousands died, but through sheer numbers and madness, five of the Targaryen dragons lay dead by the morning. Which was perhaps too many. Thereafter, each generation of dragons grew smaller than its parents'. Their skulls used to line the throne room of the Red Keep in order of birth. The oldest, Balerion, could swallow an ox whole. The last skull was barely the size of a dog's.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 4 Histories & Lore, "Dragons"</sub>

Whilst this doesn't give too much detail we do see the weapons being used in the imagery and Hobb the Hewer slaying Shrykos with his axe.

[image: Storming of the Dragonpit as depicted in the Histories & Lore]

To get more detail into some of the deaths here we can look to book material to explain it further.

> Shrykos was the first dragon to succumb, slain by a woodsman known as Hobb the Hewer, who leapt onto her neck, driving his axe down into the beast’s skull as Shrykos roared and twisted, trying to throw him off. Seven blows did Hobb deliver with his legs locked round the dragon’s neck, and each time his axe came down he roared out the name of one of the Seven. It was the seventh blow, the Stranger’s blow, that slew the dragon, crashing through scale and bones into the beast’s brain.
>
> Morghul, it is written, was slain by the Burning Knight, a huge brute of a man in heavy armor who rushed headlong into the dragon’s flame with spear in hand, thrusting its point into the beast’s eye repeatedly even as the dragonflame melted the steel plate that encased him and devoured the flesh within.
>
> [...]
>
> Many a conflicting tale is told of the death of the queen’s dragon. Some credit Hobb the Hewer and his axe, though this is almost certainly mistaken. Could the same man truly have slain two dragons on the same night and in the same manner? Some speak of an unnamed spearman, “a blood-soaked giant” who leapt from the Dragonpit’s broken dome onto the dragon’s back. Others relate how a knight named Ser Warrick Wheaton slashed a wing from Syrax with a Valyrian steel sword. A crossbowman named Bean would claim the kill afterward, boasting of it in many a wine sink and tavern, until one of the queen’s loyalists grew tired of his wagging tongue and cut it out. The truth of the matter no one will ever know—except that Syrax died that night.
>
> <sub>*The Princess and the Queen*</sub>

Drogon also seems to get hurt by the wights that crawl on him in Season 8 Episode 3, "The Long Night" and similarly he is harmed by the arrows in Season 7 Episode 4, "The Spoils of War", and Season 5 Episode 9, "The Dance of Dragons", whilst protecting Dany in the fighting pits at Meereen. As such we can expand upon this to assume had he been damaged enough at these times he might have perished.

Comment: Additionally, Drogon needing to escape the wights crawling all over him in S08E03 suggests that Drogon can't just shrug the melee damage off. It seemed to hurt him (or would have eventually hurt him), even if it would clearly take many stabs to actually significantly wound him.

Comment: Your answer seems to consider only martial damage. What about poisons?  Feed the dragon a poisoned sheep? I haven't read the books and have no idea if dragons *can* be poisoned in GoT.

Comment: @Amy As far as I'm aware there is no evidence either way for poisoning a dragon.

Comment: @Amy There was a fan theory that the Maesters were involved in poisoning the dragons and trying to kill them off but as far as I know that is solely a fan theory.

Answer (score 5):

Demonstrably, yes. You say that “all existing technology and soldiers at his command shall be considered tools”, and since his forces control King’s Landing, that includes the technology to make more scorpions. So Jon can kill a dragon in the same way as Euron did, catch it by surprise with a scorpion barrage.